# Saving only part of a collection in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jboss

I have a pretty standard @OneToMany mapping in JPA with no cascades (the default setting), like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("date")
private List<ItemRow> items;
```

My problem is, when I try to em.merge() this entity, Hibernate thinks that if an item is not present in the collection it's supposed to be removed from the database. Given that I don't call em.remove() explicitly, the resulting SQL doesn't really try to delete the items, Hibernate just tries to do `SET PARENT_ID = NULL` which fails due to database constraints, thankfully.

I don't want to load all items just to save their parent to the database. That would be silly. My user interface is paginated and when a client sends a partial collection, that doesn't mean that other items should be deleted, I just want to insert and update the rows that the user sees and leave the unlisted ones alone.

What should I do? Should I remove the collection mapping from the parent entity? **Is there a setting for “no cascading, really, use this only for loading”?**

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.4, which contains Hibernate 4.2.18.

Comment: Once you're saying you want to save the parent, and once you're saying you want to save the rows. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save only the parent. The rows will be persisted too, but that happens in another method. I just don't want em.merge(parent) to interfere with that method.

Comment: em.merge() is not the right tool. You should only send what you actually want to save to the server (i.e. the values of the form fields, typically). And all you need to do is to load the entity and modify the properties that need to be updated (i.e. what you sent from the browser).

Comment: I will give it a try. I had moved away from this pattern (load entity, modify fields and let them be saved at the end of the transaction) because only em.merge() checks `@Version`. This specific entity doesn't have `@Version`, so avoiding em.merge() might do the trick. It's really confusing tho, as I have to move between different strategies based on very subtle behaviors. I think I will try saving the rows in a different transaction too, if the changes in the parent keep interfering with the changes in the children.

Comment: That definition makes an invalid schema assuming that "ID" in ItemRow is the primary key of that entity. Either you're leaving something out or the schema's broken.

Comment: That's the primary key in the parent entity and foreign key in ItemRow. The primary key of ItemRow is something else (I've simplified the column name before posting — I have just changed it to PARENT_ID in both occurrences to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments I decided to save the parent entity with plain JDBC so I can control exactly what happens. The resulting code is kind of tedious but it's robust enough once written carefully.

After inserting or updating the parent entity I can loop thru all children and save them using JPA one by one. That part works fine.

I wish this could be more automated, but having an in-memory collection that doesn't correspond exactly to what is going to be saved seems to be a kind of unsupported operation.